# cannot read property 'iname' of undefined angular4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have this interface item.ts:-

```
export interface item{
$key?:string;
available?:boolean;
countable?:boolean;
iname?:string;
price?:string;
desc?:string;
image?:string;
}
```

The items component item.componenet.ts is :-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//import { AdditemsService } from '../../services/additems.service';
import { item } from '../../item';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-items',
  templateUrl: './items.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./items.component.css']
})
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {

items:item={
$key :"",
available :true,
countable :true,
iname :"",
price :"",
desc :"",
image :""
};

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and the html form item.componenet.html is :-

```
      <form novalidate #fo="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="mySubmit(fo)">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="iname">Item Name : </label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="iname" 
      [(ngModel)]="item.iname" #iteminame="ngModel" required minlength="3">
         </div> 
           <div *ngIf="iteminame.errors?.required && iteminame.touched" 
                     class="alert alert-danger"></div>
                  <div *ngIf="iteminame.errors?.minlength && 
                                    iteminame.touched" class="alert alert-
                                        danger"></div>
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-
                                                    success">Submit</button>
                               </form>
```

the main problem that the ngModel can not see the iname that is created in the interface. I imported the interface in the component and after that I used ngModel to get make this textbox  can add and validate on the textbox.

But I always see this error, cannot read property 'iname' of undefined.

I think the error is in this line.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="iname" [(ngModel)]="item.iname" #iteminame="ngModel" required minlength="3">
```

any help ??

Comment: Pretty sure you just have a typo - You have `[(ngModel)]="item.iname"` instead of `[(ngModel)]="items.iname"`

Comment: oh that's right , Thanks a Lot .... I am in this error for about 2 hours .... Really Thank You (Y)

Comment: No problem, we've all been there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `[(ngModel)]="item.iname"` instead of `[(ngModel)]="items.iname"`. Just a typo. There is no "item" property on your class, only "items".